# How do I list two different things in the WHERE clause in SQL?

Tags: sql

The question asks,

"List   product names   and the product vendor  for all products    where   the scale   of  the 
products    is  1:700.  (Products   table)  and the product line    is  ‘Ships’."

So far I have listed,

```
SELECT productName, productVendor 
FROM Products 
WHERE productScales = '1:700', productLine = 'Ships';
```

There is an error in the WHERE clause according to SQL. Is this not the way to put two different items in SQL? 
I appreciate any help, Thank you!

Comment: Use AND or OR instead of a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `AND` not `,`

```
SELECT productName, productVendor
FROM Products
WHERE productScales = '1:700' AND productLine = 'Ships';
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please consider to mark it as answer so the community can also benefit from it